# Using ViewPager inside Recyclerview won't show all pages of all items

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have some sliders inside recyclerview among some other items. this is my pager adapter:

```
class PagerFragmentAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


    public PagerFragmentAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

and i call setup on binding viewholder:

```
setup(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder) {
    pos = holder.getAdapterPosition();
    if (pagerHolder == null) {
        pagerHolder = (PagerHolder) holder;
        viewPager = pagerHolder.getViewPager();
        adapter = new PagerFragmentAdapter(fragmentManager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        pagerHolder.bindAdapter();
    } else if(adapter!=null)
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

the first slider in recyclerview is OK but others are not OK!!

non of the fragments are loaded! and if i scroll  it just shows first page of pager not all of them.

I have also tried creating fragments inside `getItem()` method but nothing changed..

Comment: using `android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter` now. every thing is fine now!

Comment: can you post your implementation? I need to implement an similar flow and I've encountered the same issue. Thank you.

Comment: Solved the issue, Pager Adapter was the solution, ill put up a gist with the implementation soon @IonutNegru